# How to hide the display of "Say something about this" when performing a Facebook Like

Tags: facebook

I have a problem regarding the display of the "Say something about this" when performing a like on some page in which a Like Button is put.

As you can see in the following example:

http://www.c3click.it/annunci/ripetizioni/ID-224

If you press the Like Button a "Say something about this" text appears and it's stretched, so i want to remove it and, when clicking in it, automatically obtain the affermative V with the +1 like.

How can i do it, any suggestion?

Comment: Your link take me to some (italian?) site.

Comment: Yes. I want to remove the "Say something about this" and to just let appear the +1 like button

Comment: Um, I checked it, and when I refreshed my page after clicking the button, it says I have already liked it.

Comment: Yeah...but i don't want to refresh the page to view the +1 like button. I want that this is done automatically without displaying the "Say something..."

Comment: Could you please update this question so that it does not depend on an external link? As it stands, any change to the linked page could make this question useless.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the XFBML and HTML5 versions of the Like button, people will always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the iframe version of the button, people have the option to comment if you are using the standard layout. You need to use the iframe button count option (90 x 20)